# Create Instance Using Reflection - How these methods are different?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

While working on C# Reflections, I came across these methods:
1. [Activator.CreateInstanceFrom()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fce0hc8(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createinstanceandunwrap(v=vs.110).aspx)

My questions are:
1. What does Wrap & Unwrap means?
2. How does the two methods differs?
3. The 1st method forces the user to Unwrap the object. Why?

Comment: Unwrapping an object handle has a big, big side-effect, it loads the assembly that contains the type of the object into the appdomain that made this call.  That's not always desirable if the programmer's intention was to keep that assembly isolated in another appdomain.  You therefore have to be explicit about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok,but what exactly it means to wrap/unwrap?

Comment: If you need a mental model then compare it to boxing.  But for an object created remotely.  Wrapping is like boxing, casting a reference or value to System.Object.  Unwrapping is like unboxing, casting System.Object back to its original type.  So ObjectHandle is the remoting equivalent to Object, but with a lot more work done when you unbox it.

Comment: @HansPassant Now I get it..Thanks a lot !!